# IIS: How to enable httpcompression on site level?

Tags: azure-cloud-services, http-compression

In the Azure cloud service, we have start up task to enable httpcompression at the **server** level.

```
%appcmd% set config -section:system.webServer/serverRuntime /frequentHitThreshold:"1"
%appcmd% set config -section:system.webServer/urlCompression /doDynamicCompression:"True"

%appcmd% set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /-"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='text/css']"
%appcmd% set config -section:system.webServer/httpCompression /+"dynamicTypes.[mimeType='text/css',enabled='True']"
```

Then in the **web.config**, we do this to enable httpcompression at site level:

```
<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true" doStaticCompression="true" />
```

This does not work. In IIS Manager, I can see the site level has httpcompression enabled, but the response is not compressed.

However, if I set everything to **false** in **web.config**, then manually enable the settings in IIS Manager, it then works!

Any thoughts why that happens? This needs to be automated, so even though manually setting it works, it isn't a solution for me.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938713/gzip-compression-on-iis-7-5-is-not-working) of any help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to respond back with my finding - turns out I needed to remove the **httpCompression** and **urlCompression** settings in **web.config** , then everything just worked. Feels like an IIS bug.