# compression of ico image failing on iis 7.5

Tags: web-config, compression, iis-7.5, gzip, ico

240.6 KB total in compressible text, target size = 238.2 KB - potential savings = 2.4 KB

FAILED - (3.2 KB, compressed = 0.8 KB - savings of 2.4 KB) - https://www.domain.com/favicon.ico

I have the following markup in the web.config, but it does not seem to help:

```
 <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary
 Compressed Files">
      <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
        <staticTypes>
           <add mimeType="image/x-icon" enabled="true" />
        </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938713/gzip-compression-on-iis-7-5-is-not-working