# asp.net mvc bundles gzip compresstion not work

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, bundling-and-minification, iis-8.5

My Bundle Config is like this :

```
public class BaseBundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Models").IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/models/", "*.js", true));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/framework").Include(
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/frameworkmodels.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/appbase.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/directives/directives.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/services/Services.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/controllers/controllers.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/framework/filter/filters.js",
                                            "~/Scripts/app/filter/customFilters.js"
                                            ).Include("~/Scripts/app.js"));


        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                                        "~/Content/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css",
                                        "~/Content/libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css",                                     
                                        "~/Content/libs/bootstrap/angular-csp.css",
                                        "~/Content/libs/bootstrap/mainStyle.css"
                                        ));

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;

    }
}
```

and I used bundle's inside index.cshtml like this:

```
......
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/framework")

.....
@System.Web.Optimization.Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
```

after publish on IIS 8.5. bundling and minification works as expected but bundles **are not compressed** for both ScriptBundle and StyleBundle. response content-type always is text/javascript or text/css.
why gzip compression is not working?

[image: chrome network tab screenshot]

dynamic and static content compression both are set to true in web.config

```
<system.webServer>

    <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

MVC assembly's version:
System.Web.Mvc 5.2.3.0
System.Web.Optimization 1.1.0
and Dynamic Compression module is also installed on server.

new info:
two screenshot, first is IIS request tracing log
that show dynamic compression module doing it's job, and second one is chrome network tab response headers for that request. why Transfer-Encoding:chunked and response is not gzip :\

[image: IIS Trace Log]

[image: chrome network tab]

thanks for your ideas

Comment: for IIS 7.5 but may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938713/gzip-compression-on-iis-7-5-is-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem point, hardware firewall between clients and IIS decompress gzip data and after processing content, send it chunked to client, when i try from other clients outside of company, gzip compression work as I expected.

Comment: After 3 hours of fiddling with the server this solved the problem. Is there anyway this can be overcome?

Answer (score 2):

Add an `<httpCompression>` section to your web.config before or after `<urlCompression>`.  Here is mine:

```
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\websites\_compressed" minFileSizeForComp="1024">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
    <dynamicTypes>               
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
        <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/x-javascript" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
        <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false" />
    </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

Note this doesn't kick in unless the bundle is 1024 bytes or larger (`minFileSizeForComp`) so you don't waste time compressing files that are already very small.

Note also that you'll need to make sure the gzip.dll is in this folder.

Comment: just added config but no success

Comment: Sorry that didn't work.  Did you already go through all the troubleshooting in the link James provided?  There are a lot of factors that can add up to gzip not working as you might exepct.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938713/gzip-compression-on-iis-7-5-is-not-working