# How to configure gzip in angular cli project hosted in IIS

Tags: angular, iis, compression, angular-cli, gzip

How to configure so that browser fetches gzipped compressed files in angular cli project hosted in IIs?

I have set up gzipper in angular cli project and when I execute `ng build && gzipper --verbose ./dist` and host in IIS, I can see the gzipped file served through developer tools.

**Production mode**

But when I execute `ng build --prod && gzipper --verbose ./dist`, even though the gzipped files are created in the release, served files are still the normals ones not the compressed ones.

[image]

Is there any workaround for this or should this be configured in IIS?

Comment: first, disable the iis compression. add header "content-encoding: gzip" in the iis. add mime tyep<mimeMap fileExtension=".js.gz" mimeType="application/javascript" /> which servers *.js.gz files. [link](https://gist.github.com/suhrab/552af7b3383706081fbe51c102c290d7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that SSL needs to be enabled to get the compressed files. I noticed this in Chrome and Firefox. Brotli files were served somehow, but failed for gzip in localhost and when using an IP.

Tried configuring url-rewrite, but I could notice that the files served were compressed but the header `content-encoding: gzip,br` was not applied in the response, so then the browser was unable to decompress resulting an error. This was again due to absence of SSL.

You can use url-rewrite to serve the pre-compressed files. Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48889701/setup-iis10-to-serve-pre-compressed-files/48988307?noredirect=1#comment101271682_48988307).