# How to verify if .gz files are loading in chrome browser for VueJs application?

Tags: vue.js, gzip

I have simple VueJs application with webpack and in `webpack.prod.conf.js` file, I have enabled `productionGzip` which generates `.gz` file for each of the chunks in dist folder.

```
productionGzip: true,
productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
```

When I am loading my application in browser, I can see `.js` files are loaded but I can not see any tag with `content-encoding: gzip` or anything which indicates `.gz` files has taken effects. All `.js` files loaded in network tab of browser are having `Content-Type: application/javascript`

How to verify if `.gz` files are loading in chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how your server is serving static files.

As an example, I use the simple node [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) package to test the production build.

> `-g` or `--gzip` When enabled (defaults to `false`) it will serve `./public/some-file.js.gz` in place of `./public/some-file.js` when a gzipped version of the file exists and the request accepts gzip encoding.

So I run `http-server --gzip ./dist` to serve the compiled files.

With *nginx*, you need the [`HttpGzipStatic` module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html) and to put `gzip_static on;` in your config. ([source](https://serverfault.com/a/241349/294191))

---

> Do you know how to configure IIS for this case?

It's doesn't look as straightforward to configure IIS to serve pre-compressed files, but it's easy to [tell IIS to compress static files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/702124/1218980) so you could set the `productionGzip` option to false and let IIS do the work.

[Angular's PRE-Gzipped files are not served via IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45199213/1218980) or this [ASP.Net issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2458).

Comment: Thanks for response. In my case, I am using IIS. Do you know how to configure IIS for this case?

Comment: @skubal I don't use IIS and it looks like it's not as straightforward, but there's a lot of answers on this already on SO.