# Alignment of Summarized Values in ASP.NET Web Page

Tags: asp.net, web

I have a web page that takes some values from the user and then calculations are made. These large set of calculations are displayed on the form. Sometimes, these values are saved provisionally, which means, that few summarized values will be hidden while others are displayed.

The form doesn't look so good, may be i have designed it badly but i have  used tables excessively to align and order those textboxes and labels. I have a feeling that the form loads slow too.How does the other developers design such forms where a large set of values are displayed?. Does any one know of a good site to get an idea of website designs?

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you are telling is not absolutely true. 
It hardly matters weather you use `tables` or `div`.
What you can do is use [firbug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) and [Whyslow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/yslow/) MozilaFirefox and see the time taken by each componenet.
Here is more detail about whyslow
http://yslow.org/

You can also take benefit of G-zip compression to your application.

[Setting the gzip compression in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324481/setting-the-gzip-compression-in-asp-net)

[How to implement GZip compression in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552317/how-to-implement-gzip-compression-in-asp-net)

Comment: dear i liked your answer. just one more thing. does it really matter if tables are used excessively in the web page? I was looking for some good design examples of inputting data as well as displaying some data on the form. the only way i know to align my textboxes and labels is to use tables. Am i doing it right?