# Umbraco 6 MVC on 1&1 (1and1) shared Windows hosting returns encoding error, appears to be related to gzip

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gzip, umbraco, shared-hosting

I have a basic MVC site built on Umbraco 6.1.2 and hosted with 1&1 (1and1) using their shared Windows hosting.

The site works perfectly on my local machine but once deployed it throws an encoding error on Firefox, Chrome and IE (other browsers untested, but I assume this will affect all browsers). The back office is accessible and I am able to log in and navigate through the content tree, it is just the rendering of the site content using MVC and Razor which appears to be affected by the problem.

I disabled gzip in Firefox (using this method: http://forgetmenotes.blogspot.co.uk/2009/05/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-in.html) and the website worked as expected, therefore I can only assume that this is an issue with 1&1's gzip configuration.

Has anybody had the same issue? Is it related to Umbracp or has anyone seen the same problem with standard MVC applications?

Comment: For the recors: i have the same problem => The problem is that 1&1 says that they don't use dynamic compression but all tests with fiddler gives me gzip compression if accept-encoding is set to "gzip, deflate" and then it gives an encoding error with a missing magic number. BUT: this is only occuring with umbraco rendering set to mvc. No Problems I have with umbraco rendering to webforms or with a single asp.net mvc webapp.

Comment: And also I don't get 1&1 to dig into this issue although I gave them the complete description with fiddler screenshots etc.

Comment: It's a shame they do not appear willing to help you, hopefully I will have more luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cause of the problem. I commented out all references to ClientDependency in the Web.config and now my site runs as expected. It seems as though that module is attempting to compress content but failing. This forum post helped locate the issue: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/ourumb-dev-forum/bugs/13525-Client-Dependency-Module-playing-havoc-with-gzip-content-compression

This causes some problems with the core product and is therefore not a fix, it does however give us a starting point for investigations into how the problem can be resolved.

I have updated the Umbraco issue tracker with this information. For those who are interested see here: http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-2203

Answer (score 0):

You should probably enable gzip in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\
temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
    <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll"/>
    <dynamicTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </dynamicTypes>
    <staticTypes>
      <add mimeType="text/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="message/*" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="application/javascript" enabled="true"/>
      <add mimeType="*/*" enabled="false"/>
    </staticTypes>
  </httpCompression>
  <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

There are a few more tricks here
[Setting the gzip compression in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324481/setting-the-gzip-compression-in-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric. I have tried this already with no luck, the problem is that gzip is already enabled on an IIS level and as the hosting is a shared environment I have no control over that setting. I need to switch off gzip rather than enable it.

Comment: I have also tried to switch off gzip using the urlCompression element included in your code snippet above, setting the values to false instead for both static and dynamic compression in the hope that it would override the IIS settings. On the shared hosting I am using the urlCompression element is not allowed at the website level, it appears to have been blocked lower in the configuration and throws a YSOD when set in the web.config.