# Can we make a web.config rule to redirect a request to a different file extension?

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, web-config, gzip

I have js files that are gzip on my server.
I need to redirect any request to any js files to js.gz
I know that web.config can take rules, but I am not sure how to format the rule for it to work.

Any suggestion on what the rule should look like?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7265878/6662225) work for you?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. I already use those settings are for the server to gzip the files on the fly (or cache). But the server I am using does not authorize this.
That's why I generated the gzip files and instead need the redirect.