# How to Compress an ASPX Page?

Tags: asp.net, html, compression, gzip

I followed the sample from here to compress my page:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Aspx_Compression.aspx

But the result I get is a page full of odd characters:

���`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$ؐ@�������iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼��{����{����;�N'

Not sure what's wrong with that code?

I tried the code both in Page_Load and Page_Render events.

Any idea?

Thanks,

Update:
just an update; my code was wrong! debugged it with FireBug/Net tab and it was revealed that a wrong Header was added.

Comment: Any reason not to use dynamic compression of dynamic content in IIS? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753681%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: See the SO question 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552317/how-to-implement-gzip-compression-in-asp-net

Comment: I don't have access to IIS settings on the production server so if it can be done in the code, that's preferable.

Comment: @William Do you wish to compress the CSS and javascript also?

Comment: @Prasanth; I'm using JSBuilder to compress some custom js files. but yes how would you recommend compressing all css and js files?

Answer (score 1):

Use SquishIt to compress the CSS and JavaScript. It is a very good tool

See a good [article on SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher)

You can dowload the [SquishIt from GitHub](https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt)